# Having trouble with RadiRoot in GAP

Tags: math-software, gap

I'm having trouble with [GAP - Groups, Algorithms, Programming](https://www.gap-system.org/).

I'm trying to use RadiRoot 2.7 to express the roots of a polynomial as matrices.

It works for quadratics, but fails for anything of higher degree - even the example in [the manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/radiroot/doc/manual.pdf)!

I've got GAP 4.8.8, and am running it through a terminal window on Ubuntu 17.04

Here's an example of the program working for a quadratic:

```
gap> x := Indeterminate(Rationals,"x");;
gap> f := UnivariatePolynomial(Rationals,[1,0,1]);
x^2 + 1
gap> Display(RootsAsMatrices(f)[1]);
[[0,1],[-1,0]]
```

I can't seem to get it to work for anything of a higher degree, not even the example in [the manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/radiroot/doc/manual.pdf).

```
gap> x := Indeterminate(Rationals,"x");;
gap> f := UnivariatePolynomial(Rationals,[1,3,4,1]);
x^3+4*x^2+3*x+1
gap> Display(RootsAsMatrices(f)[1]);
```

Here I just get an error message saying that there are too many arguments:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nice people at GAP Support helped me fix the problem.

I needed to replace the file `gap4r8/pkg/Alnuth-3.0.0/gp/polyfactors.gp` with

```
\\ compute factors of poly defined by coeffs over Q_f
f = subst(f,variable(f),'varA);
pol = Pol(vector(#coeffs-1,i,Polrev(coeffs[i],'varA)));
n = poldegree(f);
gettime();
fac = lift(nffactor(f, pol ));
zeit = gettime();

p2v(n,b)=vector(n,j,polcoeff(b,j-1));
f2v(n,v)=vector(#v,i,p2v(n,v[i]));

\\ print result
print("[ ");
{
  for(i=1,#fac[,1],
    for(j=1,fac[i,2],
        print(f2v(n, Vec(fac[i,1]) ),",");
    )
  );
}
print1(zeit);
print("];");
```

It seems I was experiencing problems between PARI/GP and GAP.

However, as Dima's post points out: I did not run `LoadPackage("radiroot");` inside GAP. It's too late for me to try this because I've over-written polyfactors.gp

Answer (score 3):

It works for me on a GAP 4.8.8 built from source on a x86_64 Linux.
(Edit: with Pari/GP version 2.7.1 --- it does not work with 2.9.3)

```
 ┌───────┐   GAP 4.8.8, 20-Aug-2017, build of 2017-10-15 11:23:26 (BST)
 │  GAP  │   https://www.gap-system.org
 └───────┘   Architecture: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-default64
 Libs used:  gmp, readline
 Loading the library and packages ...
 Components: trans 1.0, prim 2.1, small* 1.0, id* 1.0
 Packages:   AClib 1.2, Alnuth 3.0.0, AtlasRep 1.5.1, AutPGrp 1.8,
             CRISP 1.4.4, Cryst 4.1.12, CrystCat 1.1.6, CTblLib 1.2.2,
             FactInt 1.5.4, FGA 1.3.1, GAPDoc 1.6, IRREDSOL 1.4,
             LAGUNA 3.7.0, Polenta 1.3.7, Polycyclic 2.11, RadiRoot 2.7,
             ResClasses 4.6.0, Sophus 1.23, SpinSym 1.5, TomLib 1.2.6,
             Utils 0.46
 Try '??help' for help. See also '?copyright', '?cite' and '?authors'
gap> LoadPackage("radiroot");
true
gap> x := Indeterminate(Rationals,"x");;
gap> f := UnivariatePolynomial(Rationals,[1,3,4,1]);
x^3+4*x^2+3*x+1
gap> Display(RootsAsMatrices(f)[1]);
[ [   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0 ],
  [   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0 ],
  [  -1,  -3,  -4,   0,   0,   0 ],
  [   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0 ],
  [   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1 ],
  [   0,   0,   0,  -1,  -3,  -4 ] ]
gap>
```

How did you install GAP?

Comment: I followed the instructions on the GAP website as best as I could. I notice that you used LoadPackage("radiroot"); which I did not. Maybe that was the problem? The nice people at GAP Support sent me a patch for Alnuth "which adds support for PARI 2.9.x (by removing support for PARI 2.4.x)." I'll post the package as an answer to help other people.